# Replacing a backslash using regex is not replacing the values after a letter

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function x(input){
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    arr.push(input[i].trim().replace(/\\\\/g, "\\"));
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(x(["\\\\a\\"]));
```

I would expect this to output ['\\a\'] but instead it outputs ['\\a\\']. It's like the regex isn't being applied globally even though the global flag is set.

As a counter example, if I write:

```
var str = "\\\\a\\";

str.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\");

console.log(str);
```

I get `\\a\`, which is correct.

Comment: A second interpretation is that the regex matches the first four backslashes and turns them into two, but does not match the two backslashes, because it is looking for four of them, not two.

Comment: But backslashes are escape characters. In order to signify two I need to use four backslashes, and in order to signify one I need to use two backslashes. Is this not correct?

Comment: What happens if you try on several groups of different numbers of backslashes? Especially more than one group of four.

Comment: If I try `["\\\\\\\\a\\"]` (eight slashes before the a) I get `[\\\\a\\]`.

Comment: when i run this i get `["\a\"]`. where are you running this? (i.e. are you running it in the browser and reading the output directly off the console, or something such as running it in node and writing the console output to a file or something?) it could be that you are double escaping the output at some point.

Comment: You tried a group of eight and a group of two. How about trying two groups of four? E.g. "4-2-4-8-5-7". Two 4,  one 7. I think the 7 might be interesting, too.

Comment: I was running it in node. When I ran it in the browser I got what you did. My full version of the code is still not working properly, but at least this gave me a place to start looking. Thanks.

Comment: If I run "4-2-4-8-4" I get `[ '\\a\\a\\a\\\\a\\c' ]`. I couldn't even enter the odd numbers since I got an error on the input string. The problem seems to be the '\\'.

Answer (score 0):

`Backslash \` is a special character for both JavaScript String and Regex. So it has to be qualified by backslash.

Your expectation is incorrect as `\\` is a single character not two characters. Similarly `\\\\` is only 2 characters not 4.

```
> console.log('\\\\'.length + " : " + '\\'.length);
> 2 : 1
```

Suppose we use some other character like `Z` to represent `\\`. Then

```
\\\\a\\ = ZZaZ
/\\\\/g = /ZZ/g
```

So regex will match two occurrences of the `Z` or `\\` which match only the prefix part and not the suffix (suffix is single occurrence)

Which after replacement will give us.

```
> console.log('ZZaZ'.replace(/ZZ/g, 'Z'))
> ZaZ
```

Which is `\\a\\` if we substitute `Z` with `\\` as substituted before.

**Regarding your counter example, Strings are immutable in JavaScript, `replace()` doesn't change anything in the original String, you're logging original String.**

Which of course doesn't appear same as the `\\\\a\\` as this form is the program form where String needs to be escaped for special characters, it's length is 4 not 7. In printed for there's not need to escape backslash so you get `\\a\` in console.

Comment: My issue is that `\\\\a\\ ` is not becoming `\\a\ `. Instead I get `\\a\\ `, at least in Node. My intention is to replace all double backslashes with a single backslash. I should add that in the comments I tried this with eight backslashes and six backslashes. The eight formatted correctly, however, the six did not.

Comment: The six became `\\\\ `.

Comment: Please go through the answer carefully, `\\\\a\\` escaped form of `\\a\` so it can never become the other as it already is that. `\\a\\`is escaped form of `\a\`. `\\\\` is escaped form of `\\`. Its clearer if you think in terms of unescaped forms so `'\\\\a\\'.replace(/\\\\/g, '\\')` is escaped form of `'\\a\'.replace(/\\/g, '\')` which will replace only the prefix part. You don't have a double backslash in suffix, so you can't replace it with anything.